# How can be implemented ball moving animation in WPF using MVVM?

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, mvvm

I am trying to make simple animation using WPF. I have Canvas with drawed balls using **ItemTemplateSelector**.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cells}" Name="ItemsControlCells">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="450" Height="450">
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <selector:Selector CellWithBall="{StaticResource CellWithBall}"/>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This is example of DataTemplate.

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="CellWithBall">
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Position.x}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Position.y}"
                       Fill="{Binding Path=BallColour}" Width="{Binding Path=Size}" Height="{Binding Path=Size}"
                       Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.1">
                <Rectangle.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </Rectangle.InputBindings>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When move ball event triggers, model send to view model path. Path is list of points  that ball must go  through. Example: ball is drawed in playfield cell (0;0) (means property Position in view model is set to (0;0)). Than we want to move ball to cell (1;1). Logic get path like this {(0;0),(0;1),(1;1)}.

How can i implement this sort of animation not corrupting MVVM implementation? How can i pass path to View? Every idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to force something, which is just supposed to help you? I don't understand why so many people try so hard to "stick to mvvm" and just making very complicated stuff ... MVVM is a help, a guideline, stick to it if it suits you, and break it where its better to break it. To your question, handle the animation in your custom control, and your viewmodel is just notified or used to retrieve important data. The animation should usually be only view dependant (but again, break it if necessary) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM, I assume you have a ViewModel(VM) somewhere.  For now, lets call it 'CellAnimatorVM'.  Anyway, assuming your ItemsView will live in a Window, you want to set that Window's DataContext to be your CellAnimatorVM class.

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CellAnimatorVM/>
 </Window.DataContext>
```

Now, your 'Cells' object (the list of cells) needs to live in your CellAnimatorVM class.  Your CellAnimatorVM class will be responsible for changing the Position for each Cell in the Cells list.

In order for those changes to be communicated to your control, you need to add INotifyPropertyChanged to the Cell class and whenever the Position gets set, you need to call OnPropertyChanged("Position") from within the setter AFTER the value is set:

```
private Position _position;

public Position Position
{
   get{ return _position;}
   set
   {
      _position = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Position");
   }
}
```

This should get you hooked up.

FYI:  A simple implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged is as follows:

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Curtis, you are right. This is my real code. VM is DataContext and OnPropertyChaneged for updating View. But the problem is in animation. I simply never worked with animation. Just the simpliest tasks. So I have no idea about what control to use or whatever. @dowhilefor advice to make custom control. Good idea. Will try it soon.

Comment: So are you just moving the cells around automatically or are you moving them based on when the user clicks something? If you're moving them automatically WPF has animation built into it.  If you are moving it when the user clicks something then you can still use WPF to animate from point A to point B over some period of time and it will do it.  Here's a link to a blog with good information about how to do animation.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/15/wpf-animations-are-easy.aspx.